# Appending string does now work

Tags: nsstring

I want to combine few strings from array to create on string using the code blow:

```
NSString *resultString = @"";

for (NSString *personsName in names)
{
    [resultString stringByAppendingString:personsName];
}

return resultString;
```

Does not work. String is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write:

```
resultString = [resultString stringByAppendingString:personsName];
```

The method stringByAppendingString returns the resulting new String ;)

Comment: haha ) yep 

you are right, I forgot that it does not store a value))